# Goodman GSX140301KB Air and Fan comes on strong but air is not so cool. Why?

Tags: hvac

I am not sure if the compressor is bad or just abad capacitor. The air on all the vents come on. It is cool but not cold like the unit for my upstairs which is also the same identical unit. I checked upstairs, the air comes on cool but the one downstairs come on strong as well but the air is just slightly cool but not cold like the one upstairs (on a hot 100 degree temps). It was working well last year. Unit is 4 year old

Comment: It's more likely to be the capacitor (or contactor switch) than the compressor on a four-year old unit. Is the outside fan running at all?

Comment: Cool is a subjective term. Does the air come out cooler then it goes in, same as, or hotter? Is this consistent when it is left off for an hour then turned on?

Comment: I have the below aircon 
Goodman GSX140301KB. The capacitor is bad is this: CAP050400440CT. I see another that sells on Amazon is this:  CAP050450440CT . The difference is the 450 vs 400CT. What is the difference between them and can I use the 450440CT instead or I should should I use the original? Thanks